# Trying to find the two TV's which are defective?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> A shipment of $10$ television sets includes three that are defective. In how many ways can a hotel purchase four of these sets and recieve at least two of the defective sets?

I know that one must use the formula

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        n \\
        n_1,n_2,...,n_k  \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}= \ \frac{n!}{n_1! \cdot n_2! \cdot  \ldots \cdot n_k!}  \
$$

This is what I surmise from the information given.

$$\Rightarrow   \begin{pmatrix}
        7 \\
         2 \\ 
        \end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}
        3 \\
         2 \\ 
        \end{pmatrix} $$

How does the second sentence impact this question in getting the solution? Also why does one use the formula above to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number the TVs from 0 to 9 and say 0, 1 and 2 are defective. Then to select four TVs, at least two of which are defective, there are $\binom32\binom72+\binom33\binom71=70$ possible choices – the first term stands for "two defective TVs", the second "three defective TVs" and within each term the number of ways to select the defective, then the working TVs is listed.

Note that the second sentence says **at least** two defective TVs, which means that the hotel could choose all three of them. Your calculation is correct, but it only covers the "two defective TVs" case.

The multinomial you say is needed for the problem only appears in the form of the binomial. We use the multiplication and addition principles to obtain our result, the former because the choices of defective and working TVs are independent, and the latter because it is not possible to select "two and three defective TVs" at once.

Comment: For $\binom32\binom72+\binom33\binom71=70$ how did you get 70? Did you use the formula from the above like this $$\binom32\binom72+\binom33\binom71=70 \Rightarrow \qquad \frac{3!*7!}{2!*2!} + \frac{3!*7!}{3!*1!}$$ ?

Comment: That's not the right way to interpret binomials. Each binomial is interpreted by itself first; $\binom72=\frac{7!}{2!5!}$ for example. Then they are multiplied together (note that mathematicians almost always leave nothing between variables to be multiplied, if that is unambiguous): $3×21+1×7=70$. I also note that the other answer posted here triple-counts 7 cases and is therefore wrong.

Comment: I looked at @amwhy his answer helped greatly.

Comment: It helped me understand the formula.